# How to OR file names in open command

Tags: macos, perl, file-io

I want to pass two file names in a file open command, so that if one file doesn't exist, it should open another file.
Is there any way to do it in a single open command? Below is my code:

```
open FILE, "/Library/xampp/Documents/$var"
```

I want to pass $var such that it will have xxx | /Library/Documents/xyz. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, because you could override `*CORE::GLOBAL::open = \&some_sneaky_open_emulator`, but I recommend against that except *in extremis*, and only then with a carefully temporized `local` guard on the override.

Comment: Actually I am trying to find the vulnerability in the code. So I want to test if I can give a value to $var such that if that file doesn't exist in /Library/xampp/Documents then it should open another existing file which I provide as input in $var.

Comment: Add that comment to the body of the question, please.  It's rather an important part.

Comment: Then no, the standard `open` builtin does not behave in that fashion. But it sounds like you should be using taint mode and possibly Safe compartments.

Comment: @tchrist : Yes, I am using it. But at the same time I wanted to know what I was asking is at all possible with/without taint mode.

Comment: If you are looking for vulnerabilities, saying what OS you are using would be useful too.

Comment: @ysth : I am using osx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, yes, you can provide `$var` as "../../../any/arbitrary/file" and open a file that is not under "/Library/xampp/Documents" (though if Library, xampp, or Documents is a link rather than a file, you may need a different number of ..s).

Answer (score 3):

Does this help?

```
my $fh;

open $fh, '<', '/Library/xampp/Documents/xxx'
    or open $fh, '<', '/Library/Documents/xyz'
    or die "Unable to open files for reading: $!";
```

or perhaps

```
use List::Util 'first';

my @files = qw( /Library/xampp/Documents/xxx /Library/Documents/xyz );

open my $fh, '<', first { -f } @files or die $!;
```

Comment: This seems not best practice

Comment: OK. Actually I want to pass it as a user input. And i want to use open FILE, "/Library/xampp/Documents/$var" without making any changes to the code.

Comment: Ah. Then no - if you can't change the Perl code then you can't do it.

Comment: Your solution is what I myself first thought of, although to be honest testing for an `S_ISREG`-type “plain” file may not be the right thing in all possible cases. However, I wouldn’t go *quite* so far as to say “you can’t do it”; certainly one could, given an appropriate override of the `open` builtin.  But I certainly would not want to look myself in the mirror the next day, let alone a few years from now, as that seems like an egregious hack  belong more to the problem set than to the solution set.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes. The check should probably be that the file exists *and* is openable, but the OP did say *"so that if one file doesn't exist, it should open another file"*! As far as I can tell he wants something magic that he can enter at the program's prompt for a file name so that a single existing `open` call will choose the first value that works. No changes to the code means no overriding as well, unless you were thinking of writing a module and adding that with `-M` on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find the path to a file given an absolute path or a path relative to a directory other than the current work directory.

```
use Path::Class qw( dir file );

my $file_qfn = 'xxx';                        # /Library/xampp/Documents/xxx
   -or-
my $file_qfn = '/Library/Documents/xyz';     # /Library/Documents/xyz
   -or-
my $file_qfn = '../Docs/zzz';                # /Library/Docs/xampp/zzz

my $abs_file_qfn = file($file_qfn)->absolute(dir('/Library/xampp/Documents'));

open(my $fh, '<', $abs_file_qfn)
   or die("Can't open \"$abs_file_qfn\": $!\n");
```

You could also `chdir` to `/Library/xampp/Documents`, but I dislike doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file exists first and if it does not choose a different path.
Then open that path

```
my $path= -e $ARGV[0] ? $ARGV[0] : "default"

open(my $fh, $path) || die "$path $!"
```